# How to set the current user for WebPartManager?

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, blogengine.net

From what I've been reading, the following code should first ensure that a MembershipUser record exists for "ArthurDent", then set "ArthurDent" as the current user, and finally assign his MembershipUser record to the variable mUser.

```
if (Membership.GetUser("ArthurDent") == null)
{
   Membership.CreateUser("ArthurDent", "thisisapassword");
}
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("ArthurDent", true);
MembershipUser mUser = Membership.GetUser();
```

Instead, the variable mUser remains null.'

My goal is to programmatically set the current user to a valid record so that I can set a WebPartManager.DisplayMode on a page that started erroring out when I added BlogEngine to my web site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that BlogEngine actively suppresses the normal workings of Page.User.Identity, which Membership.GetUser() retrieves. When I replaced FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie with the following code from BlogEngine...

```
Security.AuthenticateUser("ArthurDent", "thisisapassword", true);
```

... it authenticated Arthur and logged him in.

Answer (score 0):

This problem generally occurs when the application breaks a rule defined in the web.config file. For instance I ran your code in my local environment using Windows Authentication and CreateUser at first failed because the password string was of insufficient length.   I padded the password with additional characters and was able to create user with the supplied code.  Check the  section to examine password prerequisites.
Upon first examination this looks like a configuration problem.

Comment: I've managed to create the user. After that fix, does the mUser variable get set to the expected record for you?